# How to Create a Custom Authorization for Specific User in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I know there is so many discussion on that topic but still I can't get it right (as I am beginner in MVC). I want to check permission (Edit/Delete/Update) for each user from database. Here is my database structure for better understand of this scenario: [User_MenuRole Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLhed.png)   and [User_MenuDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hgia.png)
I want to assign permission of CRUD for specific user. For say, Manager "Foo" can Create, Update but can not delete a Purchase Order.

Currently I am Using Owin/Identity for login and Authenticate User. Here is the code:

```
 public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = new UserManager().IsValid(username, password);
        if (user!=null)
        {
            var ident = new ClaimsIdentity(
                new[] { 
                    // adding following 2 claim just for supporting default antiforgery provider
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username),
                    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "ASP.NET Identity", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"),

                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,username),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid,user.UserId.ToString()), 

                    // optionally you could add roles if any
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.OperationType),
                    //new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),

                },
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(ident);
            // Set current principal
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = claimsPrincipal;

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = false }, ident);

            UserManager userManager=new UserManager();
            userManager.GetUserMenu();

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home"); // auth succeed 
        }
        // invalid username or password
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "invalid username or password");
        return View();
    }
```

**HomeController**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Manager, Admin")]
 public ActionResult Index()
   {
      //Some code
      return View();
   }
```

1. Is this possible to implement this custom authorization with this database design?
2. Can permission make with this claim system? (I guess it's not a good idea and also have anxiety of 'bad request request too long' error)
3. Can `AuthorizeAttribute` resolve this issue with this existent database? If yes then how?

Any suggestion or code appreciable.Thanks in Advance...

Comment: would [this](http://shashangka.com/2016/06/26/authorization-filters-in-asp-net-web-api-2/) help?